# I would like to know how to thicken sauces with blood and is it safe?

Tags: sauce

I saw a recipe (French) that involved thickening with blood (they also said puréed liver would work) - is this safe?  I've eaten blood sausage and black pudding, but still am curious about a sauce?

Answer (score 2):

It should be safe, you would want to follow the same precautions you would when preparing meat. I personally like thickening my stews with bone marrow.

Comment: Mmm, bone marrow!

Comment: Why not just thicken them with the animal's soul itself...Bone marrow sounds absolutely fantastic.

Comment: @if you like bone marrow you'll absolutely looove spinal cord consumme!

Comment: @mfg Depending on what animal's spine you're slurping that could be risky. If I remember correctly, eating brain and spine tissue greatly increases the risk of prion based diseases. See [Transmissible spongiform encephalopathy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmissible_spongiform_encephalopathy) and [Bovine spongiform encephalopathy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mad_cow). The important thing to note is that cooking does not prevent transmission.